# Java question for scan a binary number using while loops

Tags: java

I'm new to java, got an assignment about converting binary to decimal.

here's my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num, decimal = 0, i=0;
       
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Binary Number");
    String binary = in.nextLine();
    num = Integer.parseInt(binary);
     
    while(num != 0){
        decimal += (num%10)*Math.pow(2, i);
        num = num /10;
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("Decimal Number : "+ decimal);
}
```

It's already done but the teacher request "Use scanner class inside a while loop for users to enter the binary number one by one. A “-1” would stop the loop."

Does anyone know how to change my code?

Comment: you mean enter a binary representation of a number as a string, such as "100010111" etc?

Comment: I wonder why you convert the string of binary digits as a decimal and the reconstruct the binary digit-by-digit (the part `num%10` actually retrieves digits which you used up with `parseInt()` function) instead of just using the input _directly_....?

Comment: Additionally, be aware that interpreting an N-digit binary representation as decimal results in a number 5^(N-1) times greater than necessary. That means eg. for N=16 you may need to store a number 1000000000000000 instead of 32768. Are you sure your `int num` can accomodate the result of decimal conversion of expected input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task consists of two parts: iterated input-check-process cycle and the process itself.

The former is simply solved with a loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {

        // input
        System.out.println("Enter a Binary Number");
        String inputStr = in.nextLine();

        // check
        if (inputStr.equals("-1")) {
            break;
        }

        // process
        // TODO
    }
}
```

This repeats asking for input data, reading it, testing for a special 'terminate' value and exits eventually if one is found.

The second part can be solved as follows: scan input digits one by one; each new digit found becomes a new least-significant bit of a number being constructed, while all preceding digits become one position more significant than they were.
That means, whenever you find a new digit, the number gets doubled and the value of a new digit gets added:

```
        // process
        int result = 0;
        int position;

        for (position = 0; position < inputStr.length(); ++position) {
            char digit = inputStr.charAt(position);
            int val = Character.digit(digit, 2);

            result = 2*result + val;
        }

        System.out.println("Decimal Number : "+ result);
```

Together they make:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {

        // input
        System.out.println("Enter a Binary Number");
        String inputStr = in.nextLine();

        // check
        if (inputStr.equals("-1")) {
            break;
        }

        // process
        int result = 0;
        int position;

        for (position = 0; position < inputStr.length(); ++position) {
            char digit = inputStr.charAt(position);
            int val = Character.digit(digit, 2);

            result = 2*result + val;
        }

        System.out.println("Decimal Number : "+ result);
    }
}
```

Of course, for a real-life program we should also validate input, ie. test if it consists of digits `0` and `1` only, whether it's not empty or not too long (so that the result of conversion fits the values range of type `int`).

Answer (score 1):

Use another `while loop` and keep iterating until the user inputs -1.If user inputs -1 use `break` to come out of `while loop`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num, decimal = 0, i=0;
       
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a Binary Number");
        String binary = in.nextLine();
        num = Integer.parseInt(binary);
    
        if(num ==-1){
            break;
        }
    
        while(num != 0){
            decimal += (num%10)*Math.pow(2, i);
            num = num /10;
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println("Decimal Number : "+ decimal);
     }
}
```

Comment: Why? Can you offer any explanation why this code is better?

Comment: @CiaPan the question asked was how can he keep asking for input from user until the user inputs -1.The question does not mention  for any optimization of code.

Comment: I don't care about optimization, I'm asking for explanation. Applying a ready-to-use, but undocumented, code is a fish instead of a fishing-stick – it may patch the current problem of OP, but not necessarily gives her/him an opportunity to learn how to solve similar problems in future...

Comment: @CiaPan you are correct,i will edit my answer and provide an explanation .